# Redefining Dataframe for Regression-Analysis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

i have a dataframe with timestamps of several transportations from a to b plus information about the material (volume, weight etc.).

[image: Picture of the excel sheet I use]

I recreated the important parts of the raw excel sheet I use.

My first step is to calculate the time it needed by simply substracting the dates as i only need a daily precision. I put all the times in a numerical vector to have it easy for further calculations and plots.

BUT:
I'd like to perform a regression analysis on it. I know how to create an lm.
My problem is, Due to several NA's my numerical vector of "transport days" is shorter than my cols in the df.
How can I merge the cols from the df with my numerical vector so that the transport times match the several materials again?

Comment: Could you provide some data to copy and paste in R, and a desired output.

Comment: Can you share how you created "transport days" and the structure of your r df (using pdut)?

Comment: If I can understand your question correctly, you don't have to remove `NA`s from your data to run a regression with `lm`. But if for some reason you want to remove `NA`s then you can simply do `data <- data[!is.na(data$\`transport days\`, ]`.

Comment: I just created a numerical vector of times. like df$t4 - df$t1. In this process, the NAs get sorted out automatically. Now I search for a possibility to merge the volume cols to the num vec in a new df to perform a regression analysis over it.

Comment: Why do the NAs get sorted out automatically? `df1<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=c(1,1,NA,2,NA));
df1$a-df1$b
[1]  0  1 NA  2 NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look for something like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(t4-t1))
```

You then have a time difference column while the colume column is still in the df. You can tell `lm()` how to deal with NAs anyway, so you don't need to drop them (I also don't think that you were doing it anyway).